# php image filter function with image uri data

Tags: php, image-processing, imagefilter

i have a based 64 image uri and decoding it ,but the issue is, i dont know how to apply php image filter function, how do i make the image filter function access the image data and later upload the filtered image to mysql database. Though i'v tried using `imagecreatefromstring`,i think i'm doing it wrong. I'd be glad if i can get any advice.
Thanks

`$code_base64="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABk........`
`

```
$base_to_php = explode(',', $baseFromJavascript);

$data = base64_decode($base_to_php);
```

Comment: You can save the image to a file, and then apply filter and then delete it when you are done

Comment: @abeyaz thanks, all this done in php?

Answer (score 1):

The explode() method returns an array and the base64_decode() method expects a string, so that is one thing you could look into.

I think it should be this?

```
if( isset($base_to_php[1]) && ! empty($base_to_php[1]) )
{
    $data = base64_decode($base_to_php[1]);
}
```

... depending how many comma's there are in this $code_base64 string to begin with, of course